# only keep the value of a column in first match after merging, for rest it can be 0.0

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `pandas` `dataframe`, one has columns `a`, `b`, `c` & other has column `a`, `b`, `d`.

`df1`

```
id  month   c
1   1   TE
2   1   TE
1   1   NTE
2   1   NTE
```

`df2`

```
id  month   price
1   1   4
2   1   6
```

I want to merge these dataframes on `id` & `month` columns combinedly. so i did following -

`df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['id', 'month'], right_on=['id', 'month'])`

results of above code is as expected. now, what i want is, after merge, only one pair of `id` & `month` should have `price`, other pair have price as 0

so the result should be like

```
id  month   c   price
1   1   TE  4
2   1   TE  6
1   1   NTE 0
2   1   NTE 0
```

Above can be done, while calling a check one each row, which i think is very expensive, `n*n` complexity.

Any leads with less expense is most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

```py
df.price *= ~df.groupby(["id", "month"]).cumcount().astype(bool)
```

i use `.cumcount()` as a "is this first in the group" mask:

```py
In [89]: df
Out[89]:
   id  month    c  price
0   1      1   TE      4
1   2      1   TE      6
2   1      1  NTE      4
3   2      1  NTE      6

In [90]: df.groupby(["id", "month"]).cumcount()
Out[90]:
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64

In [91]: ~_.astype(bool)
Out[91]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

In [92]: df.price *= _

In [93]: df
Out[93]:
   id  month    c  price
0   1      1   TE      4
1   2      1   TE      6
2   1      1  NTE      0
3   2      1  NTE      0
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
merged = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['id', 'month'])  

def f(x):
    x.iloc[1:] = 0
    return x

merged['price'] = merged.groupby(['id', 'month'])['price'].transform(f)
```

Note: if they are the same, you don't have to specify
`left_on` and `right_on` separately.

Comment: short & precise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `cumcount` as grouper and fill the rest:

```
cols = ['id', 'month']
(df1.assign(rank=df1.groupby(cols).cumcount())
    .merge(df2.assign(rank=0), how='left',
           on=cols+['rank'])
    .fillna({'price': 0}, downcast='infer')
    .drop(columns='rank')
)
```

output:

```
   id  month    c  price
0   1      1   TE      4
1   2      1   TE      6
2   1      1  NTE      0
3   2      1  NTE      0
```

###### different column names

```
cols_left = ['id', 'month']
cols_right = ['id', 'month']
(df1.assign(rank=df1.groupby(cols_left).cumcount())
    .merge(df2.assign(rank=0), how='left',
           left_on=cols_left+['rank'],
           right_on=cols_right+['rank'])
    .fillna({'price': 0}, downcast='infer')
    .drop(columns='rank')
)
```

Comment: how about if cols are different for both the dataframe, i mean if the column name in df1 is `month_new` and in df2, it's `month`?

Comment: @ggupta then just use `left_on`, `right_on` as you did, I only removed it here as it was not important for the the question. See edit.

Comment: would be great for others if you just a brief explanation, about `cumcount` & `assign`

Comment: @ggupta `groupby.cumcount` will assign a counter per group. 0 for the first group item, 1 for the second etc. See. `df1.assign(rank=df1.groupby(cols).cumcount()`. In parallel we assign 0 in a new column in `df2` (see. `df2.assign(rank=0)`). Now only the first value will be used for the `merge`.